# Join two tables with almost the same fields and check when two fields are different

Tags: postgresql, join, dbeaver

I need your help and I'll try to explain with a simple example.

I have Table A:

| NAME | CITY | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lucas | Dallas | 21 |
| John | Chicago | 30 |
| Tim | London | 15 |

and Table B:

| NAME | CITY | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lucas | Dallas | 21 |
| John | Chicago | 45 |
| Tim | London | 15 |

I want to join these two tables and I want that, where there's a difference (in the example, John's age), the result is NULL.
Consider that this is a simple example, in reality I have a lot more fields and I won't know before which values are different (so I can't use "AGE ISNULL", because the difference could be also in CITY).
The only field that will never be different is NAME.

Thank you in advance for your help!

I tried using left join but, instead of giving me 'NULL' where there's a difference, I have two lines, for example:

| NAME | CITY | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Chicago | 30 |
| John | Chicago | 45 |

I want only one line with NULL in the age.

Comment: This is a bit suspect without a key for the name.  How do we know there's not two John's in Chicago with ages 30 and 45?  Combining the records could be consolidating data that shoudln't be. (granted this is a "Simple" example" so maybe it's not a problem) but we need a minimially complete verifiable example to help work through the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can combine an LEFT JOIN with a CASE statement to get the desired outcome of having NULL where there is a discrepancy between the two tables and just having one line with NULL values. Here is how to go about it:

```
SELECT 
    A.NAME, 
    A.CITY, 
    CASE WHEN A.AGE = B.AGE THEN A.AGE ELSE NULL END AS AGE
FROM 
    TableA A
LEFT JOIN 
    TableB B ON A.NAME = B.NAME AND A.CITY = B.CITY;
```

Based on the matching NAME and CITY fields in both records, the LEFT JOIN will merge the rows from both tables in this query. The SELECT clause's CASE statement determines whether the AGE values in the two tables are equal. If they match, it will show the AGE value from Table A; if not, NULL will be shown. This will result in a single line for each distinct NAME and CITY combination, with NULL appearing in the AGE column in cases when the two tables differ.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer :) I've tried this solution, but what I get is two lines: one with AGE=NULL and one with the AGE=45 (age of table B)

Comment: let me have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

You can `LEFT JOIN` the send table B and only select Values from A

```
SELECT A."NAME", A."CITY", NULL as AGE FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN B
  ON A."NAME" =  B."NAME" AND  A."CITY" = B."CITY" AND  A."AGE" = B."AGE"
WHERE b."NAME" IS NULL
```

| NAME | CITY | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Chicago | *null* |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mQjxBx_A)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Btw, looking at the attached example, I see that this way you obtain two lines? I need one with JOHN | CHICAGO | NULL

Comment: I updaed my answer

Comment: Hi, this way I force the field to be null. In reality, I won't know which is the different value

Comment: your comment says `JOHN | CHICAGO | NULL` and this is what the Query returns, if you need another output you need to specify it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of join use set based operations. Set based operations allow us to compare one data set to another (All of A except those in B).

Keep in mind my example will compare every record and column to every record and column and show you when differences are found in any column.  One can limit the columns for evaluation by specifying the columns desired for comparison instead of the * I use.

If we can assume table A and Table B have the exact same structure and data types and in the same order, then you can minus (except) B From A giving you all the differences for A, then union the inverse to get all the differences in B.

The except operator essentially eliminates like records from the result set when where a matching record is found in the B data set (all columns must match) from A; thus showing us differences in set A not in B.  We do the inverse B except A and get differences in B not A and then union the results together. to get when a difference exists on a record for the desired columns defined.

```
(SELECT * FROM Table A  -- Substitute your columns for comparison instead of * in all of the 4 * cases.
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM table B)

UNION ALL
(
SELECT * FROM TABLE B
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TABLE A)
```

Alternatively you could union the two tables together A and B
Group by the fields that you want to compare and get a count.  Then return only those having a count = 1; though this assumes no duplicate records would exist in either data base set(A,B); though that could be manged with a subquery and a select distinct.

Something like...

```
With CTEA as 
(SELECT DISTINCT * From A),
CTEB as (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM B)
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM CTEA
UNION 
SELECT * FROM CTEB)
GROUP BY (Fields for compare)
HAVING COUNT =1
```

Those with a count of 2 would have records in both A and B and we don't want those.  THe distinct used in the CTE's would ensure we don't evaluate duplicates in a single set; which would cause our count to be 2 on such records.

[More on set based operations with posgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html)

[More on set based operations in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL))

Comment: Though this doesn't just give you one line, it shows both lines so you can see the difference...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(A.NAME, B.NAME) AS NAME,
CASE 
    WHEN A.NAME IS NULL THEN B.CITY
    WHEN B.NAME IS NULL THEN A.CITY
    WHEN A.CITY <> B.CITY THEN NULL
    ELSE A.CITY
END AS CITY,
CASE 
    WHEN A.NAME IS NULL THEN B.AGE
    WHEN B.NAME IS NULL THEN A.AGE
    WHEN A.AGE <> B.AGE THEN NULL
    ELSE A.AGE
END AS AGE
FROM TableA A
FULL OUTER JOIN TableB B ON A.NAME = B.NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [distinct on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) in combination with `case` conditions in a sub-select. The sub-select identifies the rows with differing city and/or age. The outer query eliminates duplicate `names` where at the resulting city or age differs. (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5IGye08t).)

```
select distinct on (name)
       name 
     , city
     , age
  from (select a.name 
             , case when a.city = b.city then a.city else null end city 
             , case when a.age = b.age then a.age else null end age  
          from table_a  a
          join table_b  b
            on (a.name = b.name)
        ) sq
 where city is null 
    or age is null
 order by name;
```